# Capybara-webkit takes lots of memory. How could I release it?

Tags: webkit, capybara, capybara-webkit

I am making an web scraping app by using Rails 4. I chose capybara-webkit for browser engine. It looks the scraping app is running well and I can parse the data what I need.

The problem is memory. The process called "webkit-server" is taking lots of memories while my app is performing its scraping process and I am assuming that capybra-webkit is using the process by somehow.

Since, it tends to occupy about 1GB after scraping few hundreds pages, I want to limit/clear the memory occupation.Is there any way to do that?

It looks Selenium is free from the memory issue (keeps occupying not more than 300mb around), but it runs slower than webkit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `reset!` occasionally on the driver instance.

The driver is written with automated test suites in mind, and it doesn't perform some kinds of cleanup until `reset!` is called. It's normally invoked between each test.

If the process is holding onto an unusual amount of memory after calling `reset!`, you've found a bug in the driver.

Comment: I tried to call 

 Capybara.reset_sessions!

after my app saved some records.

The reset is working, but it looks reset!  clears every session data including login infomation, I need to fire login session again (console says it could not find some elements which can found in pages if it could pass through login session)...

Joe, thanks anyway.

Comment: May be I can add new code which try resetting session after the several crawling sessions.